Why do columns I add to the Site Pages library not appear in crawled properties?
I want to add a column to the Sites Pages library in my SharePoint online site, as i want to use this field to filter items in a News web part. My problem is that the column never shows up in crawled properties, even after waiting for multiple days. I guess I'm missing something, and i could need some help?
On a side note: if a add a new column to any other lists in the same site, they show up in crawled properties. It's just the columns I add in the Site Pages library that doesn't?
Here is what I've tried so far:

Create a new SharePoint site
Added a new "Single Line of Text" as well as "Choice" column to the Site Pages library
Added content to some of the column items
In the Site Pages library settings -> Advanced settings -> I ran "Reindex Document library"
In Site Settings -> Search -> Search and offline availablity:

Checked that "Allow this site to appear in search results?" is set to "Yes"
Run the "Reindex site



...I then waited for at least 2 days, but nothing show up in my crawled properties?
I also tried to add a new Managed metadata column to the Site Pages library:
In Sharepoint admin interface -> Content services -> Term store:

Created a new term group, term set, and term.

In the SharePoint site:

Added a Managed metadata column to the Site Pages library
Tagged a few items with my newly created term from the Term store
In the Site Pages library settings -> Advanced settings -> I ran "Reindex Document library"
In Site Settings -> Search -> Search and offline availablity:

Checked that "Allow this site to appear in search results?" is set to "Yes"
Run the "Reindex site



